# Todo with user input

Tags: php

I'm searching for a todo-list application like this one http://diggan.se/todo/ but with a function so the users could add todo's that would look like requests. Me (the webmaster) can later choose which request I should start working on or trash another request. The application should be for small projects.

Thanks ahead, Victor!

Answer (score 1):

how about 37signals Tada list:
http://tadalist.com/

Comment: When you share the list, does that mean anyone can edit it (without an account)?